# crystal report showing error --> Database connector error: 'Cannot obtain error message from server'

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to work on a already existing crystal report file. It has given to me by someone else.

It has two table in its `'Database fields'`. When i try to run it in my system it runs properly.

But i need to edit this report and add some new columns in it so when i have added 1 more table to Database field and uses some data from that newly added table in my crystal report it gives This error

```
"Database connector error: 'Cannot obtain error message from server".
```

Please can somebody tell me how to remove this error?

Comment: Did you add the table from an existing data source, or did you add a new data source?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to verify database option of Table.if not then in database field click the 
verify database on your table properties it will work.